# Python- turn values in a dictionary into a list

Tags: python

i have a question:

I have a dictionary like this

`{1: [4, 2, 1, 3], 2: [4, 3, 1, 2], 3: [4, 3, 1, 2]}`

and I want to get each of the values into their own list within a loop
eg.

```
for each key in myDict
    myList = [4,2,1,3]
```

do something in my list/ clear my list then loop around so...

`myList = [4,3,1,2]`

I have no idea how to attempt this, does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Question is unclear. what are you expecting

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries have `a.values()` method, and you can use it like so:

```
for myList in myDict.values():
    print(myList)  # Do stuff
```

Keep in mind camelCase isn't a convention in Python.

Answer (score 0):

solution of you problem

```
a={1: [4, 2, 1, 3], 2: [4, 3, 1, 2], 3: [4, 3, 1, 2]}
mylist=a[1]
print(mylist)
```